# Test if file is mac alias

Tags: java, macos, file

In windows, shortcuts are files that have a .lnk extension and contain roughly half a kilobyte of contents that points to another file. However, in mac, an alias is treated as if it is the file it is pointing to, and reading from/writing to the alias will do so to the file it is pointing to. Is there a way to test if a particular `File` object is an alias in mac?

Comment: You mean a symbolic link?

Comment: I guess? I right click on the file and then click "make alias", so that's what I've always called it

Comment: An alias is a thing in the terminal (shortcut to another command, but not a file). A symbolic link is created by `ln -s` in the terminal. I'm not sure what the right click menu does